# RSS Feed with javascript android

Tags: android, rss, android-webview

Is it possible to load RSS feed using JavaScript that will be displayed into Android? I have done several research but I can't grapse the logic when running JavaScript inside my android application. It seems that they are two world apart thought we have webview. Suppose I have this link http://france.meteofrance.com/portlet/plugins/mete/VignetteMeteoVille3.javascript?idLieu=431200, how can I load it in a webview?

Answer (score 0):

For security and performance reasons, javascript is disabled by default on WebView. You need to enable it with [setJavaScriptEnabled](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#setJavaScriptEnabled%28boolean%29)

```
webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
```

Comment: ok but i want to know how to do the rss feed with javascript inside the webview.. is it possible ?

Comment: A WebView displays web pages (see here: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). I don't think your JavaScript generates any html and I'm not sure to understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: i am implementing a meteo rss feed dude

Comment: I understand that but you're gonna need more than the link you provided for that. Anyway, you should look into that, it should provide you all the informations you need : http://developer.android.com/guide/webapps/webview.html

Comment: thanks for the webview tutorial but its not what i am looking for dude.